# using lambda, filter for extracting values from a dictionary based on list key values

Tags: python, lambda, filter

I have this `dictionary_pair` and a `list_value`. I want to be able to use `lambda`, filter to get a list as `[1,2]`. I have tried the code below but getting a list as `['ab']`.

```
dictionary_pair = {'ab': [1, 2], 'cd': [3, 1]}

list_value = ['ab', 'yz']

try:  
    result = list(filter(lambda x: dictionary_pair[x], list_value))
except KeyError:  
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just to show you how to use `lambda`, `map`, `filter`. However a simple `list-comprehension` is preferred in this case

```
list(filter(None, map(lambda x:dictionary_pair.get(x, None) ,list_value)))
#[[1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want something like this:

```
result = [v for k, v in dictionary_pair.items() if k in list_value]
```

No need to use a lambda, a simple list comprehension works here.

Comment: Just to say there is a typo: "if k in list_value]". It is of course an "if" and not "id